# Increment in (a, b = b, a + b) while using a Generator Function

Tags: python, fibonacci

Can someone explain how the increment of `a` or value of `a` occurs within the for loop to generate the Fib sequence?
I have an understanding of (a, b = b, a + b). However, I am unable to figure how the increment occurs in the for loop when **next**() is called.

```
 def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
x = fib(4)
print(x.__next__())
print(x.__next__())
print(x.__next__())
print(x.__next__())
```

0
1
1
2

Comment: `b` is incremented by `a`, and `a` is assigned to `b` n the next iteration. Could you elaborate on what you are confused about?

Comment: Every time you run `__next__` on a generator, it runs until the next `yield`. `__next__` returns that value and the generator function gets paused there.

Comment: Your question seems to be a basic question about how generators work and doesn't really involve `a,b = b, a+b`. Think of `yield` as sort of like `print`. If you would have no problem understanding how the code would work with `print()` then you shouldn't have any problem with `yield`:  `print` prints to the screen, `yield` "prints" to the future. `__next__` is just a way of seeing the next value "printed"

Comment: when you use `yield` instead of `return` then it create generator. When you run it with next() then it run till `yield`, and it exits (like `return`) but when you run it again then it start at `yield` so it continue loop, it not start at the beginning of function.

Comment: I get the yield/next part. My question is for n=1,2,3. How does `a` increment to generate the Fib sequence in (a,b = b, a+b)

Comment: If you wonder how values of `a` and `b` are passed from one step to the next, then I would agree with @JohnColeman and feel that your understanding of this is related to [the more general question about generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232350/how-generators-work-in-python).

Comment: “I have an understanding of (a, b = b, a + b)” – so this is not accurate?

Comment: To the best of my understanding as explained (a, b = b, a + b) in some other post. Meaning the expressions on the right are evaluated first.

Comment: Even if that's a duplicate, I think the other question would deserve a second answer on an higher level of abstraction ([the current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25233077/1720199) is very technical and go into implementation details that might not be of interest for everyone).

Comment: There is another duplicate of this question. On this one I feel like both the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756156/1720199) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1932598/1720199) are reasonable answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you can go to the next element of the generator by `next(x)`.

Just using a print statement in your code will help you understand as well.

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        print(a, b)
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

x = fib(4)
print(next(x))
print(next(x))
print(next(x))
print(next(x))
0 1
0
1 1
1
1 2
1
2 3
2
```

Here the next function lazily evaluates and prints out the value of a, until you call `next` again. 
So in the first next, it prints out 0.
Then when you call next again, a = 1 and b = 1, and you get a = 1.
Then when you call next again, a = 1 and b = 2, and you get a = 1.
Then when you call next again, a = 2 and b = 3, and you get a = 2.
After that, since you are done with your for loop, you cannot call next anymore