# How do generators (yield) work on the low-level?

Tags: generator, low-level, conceptual

I know the concept of generators (usually `yield`) that most scripting languages provide (like PHP or Python), so how to use them, how they work and what benefits (less clutter, more performance, less memory) they usually have *within the scope of the language itself*.

My question targets an explanation of how they work under the hood. Somehow a state must be stored somewhere outside the scope of the language itself. And this "somehow" must be a very generic concept, because I can use generators like any normal function that would return an array otherwise.

For example, if I call functions from binary libraries--like querying MySQL inside a PHP generator--somehow the state of the database connection has to be kept alive. So a generator has to interfere somehow with an external application (MySQL server in this case) which normal code execution within the language does not allow directly, usually. Normal functions would only allow to use the provided API functions from the library, but using generators seem to have some automagic concepts to soften this restriction and provide the initially named benefits that generators often yield (pun intended).

So, what are the basic concepts of how to provide a generator from the POV of a language/interpreter designer?

([How are generators and coroutines implemented in CPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389812/how-are-generators-and-coroutines-implemented-in-cpython) is not a duplicate, IMHO, because I'm not asking for a specific implementation of CPython, but the general ideas behind them.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are generators and coroutines implemented in CPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389812/how-are-generators-and-coroutines-implemented-in-cpython)

Comment: Read more about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)